# supervisord: Don't start a program before another one is running

Tags: supervisord

I am using supervisor on Ubuntu with several programs to supervise. Is it possible to configure supervisor so it doesn't start a program before another specific program has successfully started?

I.e. I want to run Kafka only after Zookeeper has started.

Answer (score 9):

You can't do this, as far as I know. See this issue:
https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/122

One commenter there suggests having all your programs as autostart = false, except just one, that has the responsibility for bringing all the others up (using supervisorctl, or the API, I guess) in the right order.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure supervisor can ensure that but try to specify Zookeeper's [priority](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-values) lower than Kafka's, something like this:

```
[program:Zookeeper]
command=xx
priority=1
autostart = true
autorestart = true

[program:Kafka]
command=yy
priority=999
autostart = true
autorestart = true
```

Comment: Doesn't work :(